# (OS X tar) Difference Between -H and -L Flags On Tarball Creation

Tags: macos, archive, tar, symlink

I'm rather perplexed by these two options and **how they affect the final archive** when using tar on Mac OS X.

From the man page:

```
 -H      (c and r mode only) Symbolic links named on the command line will be followed;
         the target of the link will be archived, not the link itself.

 -L      (c and r mode only) All symbolic links will be followed.
         Normally, symbolic links are archived as such.
         With this option, the target of the link will be archived instead.
```

Would that mean the -H is for files you manually symlinked?
How would tar know what *you* symlinked vs what was *automatically symlinked* (by say an installer if that's a thing)

**Context**: I have a directory structure that has a symlinked subdirectory pointing to another disk entirely.  I want to fully include those files in the tar as if they were local.  Both -H and -L look to do what I need, but I need a solid understanding of how they differ before I commit.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you need to manually pass to -H those symlinks that you want followed? it says "...named on the command line..." so I guess that means those that you specify after -H maybe?

Comment: I thought about that, but it's not consistent with other options that do require entries to be entered at time of execution.  -H really appears to be standalone.

Comment: I guess you could test them both on a subdir and see what happens? The wording is definitely not 100% clear.